# Sort by specific object key

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects like this:

```
    const cars = [
    {
        id: 'a1c1',
        position: 3,
        name: 'Car 3',
    },
    {
        id: 'b9f6',
        position: 1,
        name: 'Car 1',
    },
    {
        id: '3b6d',
        position: 2,
        name: 'Car 2',
    },
];
```

and now I am sorting it by position, from first to last, like this:

```
const sorted = cars.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
```

and then I have an object with ranks and these rank values are the same ids from the cars object:

```
const carsByRank = {
    good: 'b9f6',
    best: '3b6d',
    average: 'a1c1',
};
```

What I need to get from this data: When I sort the data, I need the best car to be the first, good second, average third, and any other that will not have a rank, goes under these. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Of the above, in particular *search* -- this has been asked and answered in various forms many, many times.

Comment: @AdilBimzagh the `id` can be a string of random characters, so this will not work.

Comment: Think through sort: if an item comes before, return -1 (so if the id matches "best", return -1), otherwise, *check the other conditions* and return -1, `0`, or `1`, depending on how you want them to order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "best" comes first, that is your first check inside `sort` to return `-1` (a comes before b) or `1` (a comes after b).
Then check for "good", then "average".

That gets best, good, and average as your first three. You can then continue to order by position if desired.

**Note:** `Array.prototype.sort` does return the sorted array, but also modifies the original array

I've added some additional objects to better show sorting and subsequent position based sorting.

```js
const cars = [{
    id: 'a1c1',
    position: 3,
    name: 'Car 3',
  },
  {
    id: 'a2a2',
    position: 5,
    name: 'Junker 1'
  },
  {
    id: 'a2a3',
    position: 6,
    name: 'Junker 2'
  },
  {
    id: 'b9f6',
    position: 1,
    name: 'Car 1',
  },
  {
    id: 'a2a4',
    position: 7,
    name: 'Junker 3'
  },
  {
    id: '3b6d',
    position: 2,
    name: 'Car 2',
  },
  {
    id: 'a2a5',
    position: 4,
    name: 'Junker 4'
  },
];

const carsByRank = {
  good: 'b9f6',
  best: '3b6d',
  average: 'a1c1',
};

/* sort is in-place and modifies the array */
cars.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.id === carsByRank.best) return -1;
  else if (b.id === carsByRank.best) return 1;
  else if (a.id === carsByRank.good) return -1;
  else if (b.id === carsByRank.good) return 1;
  else if (a.id === carsByRank.average) return -1;
  else if (b.id === carsByRank.average) return 1;
  else return a.position - b.position;
});

console.log(cars);
```